# maxSpeed tags versus default speeds

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

I am using osm2po to load the Europe dataset into a PostGIS database to use with pgRouting.

I find the default speeds in osm2po.config to work quite well, but when a maxSpeed tag is found this speed is used as-is to compute the cost.
Shouldn't it somehow be lowered by some ratio ? When used like this, osm2po underestimates the driving time IMHO.

i.e. in Belgium the maxSpeed on motorways is 120 km/h, but I'd rather use an average speed of 110 km/h.

Is it possible to either specify a ratio to apply to maxSpeed tags, or maybe some a conversion table of some sort ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, this would be a good idea and more realistic.
However, I do not want to pump up osm2po with too many extra stuff.
These specials must be implemented on code level. The framework can be easily customized. Look for WayTagResolver - There are many examples here in the forum.

Comment: OK, I understand, but what about just flagging the way has having computed estimated with a maxSpeed tag ? This way one could add some logic after the processing, i.e. maximinize the cost by a certain amount on all costs that have been computed with maxSpeed ? Otherwise I'll give the WayTagResolver a look, but I know almost nothing of Java so it might be a bit diffcult to get it to work.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your alternative would be some kind of postprocessing? If so, you can add a 'flag' to the flagList, 'hasMaxSpeed' e.g.. In combination with a decl like `wtr.allow.maxspeed=hasMaxSpeed` you'll get an additional flag indicating the existence of an overwritten maxspeed. Maybe this helps.